# Disabling country code suffix in Windows Open dialog

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

I'm trying to follow the Adobe Illustrator file recovery routine described here:
http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/enable-content-recovery-mode-illustrator.html
but I'm stuck at step 3 (holding Ctrl + Alt + Shift) - in fact, when I hit Open, the windows appends the file name with web country code (in my case .pl) - making the file selection invalid (such as myfile.ai.pl)

I think this is a web browser (probably IE) shortcut behavior - how can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: In IE go to `Internet Options / General tab` and click the **Languages** button, then delete the suffix (must be set to .PL in your case):

[image: 1]

Close IE and try again in Illustrator.